# DataGridView Update

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I'm using 2005 Windows Forms in C#.  I've only been working at this for a day, so go easy please.

I'd like to have a submit button that saves changes to a DataGridView.  I've gotten data into the DGV and can edit, but am stuck on the Update().

I've created an .xsd named scDB and one DataTable called -  SSIS Configurations Staging.  I then added a new query that takes a parameter.

Here is my code so far:

```
//Declared at top of form class    
scDBTableAdapters.SSIS_Configurations_StagingTableAdapter myStagingTableAdapter = new scDBTableAdapters.SSIS_Configurations_StagingTableAdapter();


//After a form event            
stagingGrid.DataSource = myStagingTableAdapter.GetDataBy(filterName.Text.ToString());

//On Submit click:

myStagingTableAdapter.Update(?What Goes Here?);
```

What gets passed to the Update method?  I know it needs a dataTable, but I don't know how to reference what is in the GridView.  In most code examples people define the DataTable - but I do not.  I assume this is being done behind the scenes when I created the TableAdapter.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sam,

the update needs a table so you could try something like:

```
TableType table = (TableType) stagingGrid.DataSource;
myStagingTableAdapter.Update(table);
```

where you'll have to substitute TableType with something appropriate.

But a better approach would be to use drag-and-drop and learn form the code.

1. Select Data|View Datasources. Your
   dataset should be visible in the
   DataSources Window.
2. Drag a table to
   a (new) form. VS2005 will add a load
   of components and a few lines of
   code.

The form will now have a instance of the dataset and that is your reference point for Adapter.Fill and .Update methods.

Comment: Yes, that worked, but I'll try what you've mentioned.  Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170268/how-to-update-the-datagridview-when-editing-is-made can you help me sir

Answer (score 1):

Update on a table-adapter needs a **DataSet**.

You need to instantiate a *scDB* *DataSet* with the table, update that table and call to  *Update* for the table-adapter.

Comment: Yes, but I don't define any of this, how can I find what it is called?  If I try to use scDB it tells me it is a type...which makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you've configured the proper TableAdapter to go with the DataTable specified (Right-Click on the TableAdapter section and select "Configure...'), you'll have a wide variety of options.

After doing this on my own DataTables I'm able to update by

- Strongly Typed DataTable
- DataSet
- DataRow DataRow() - Array of DataRows if multiple require updating
- Individual Columns (provided you have unique key to tie the row to)