# OleDbDataAdapter: cannot update database

Tags: c#, winforms, oledbdataadapter

I've been working on this since yesterday and I just can't update my database.
There are 3 tables. Here is a piece of code of one of WinForms. It loads data and display but after changing sth manually in the grid I get either errors by calling Update or anything happens at all.

please help because I'm going crazy.

```
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
    //instance fields
    private export2Excel export2XLS;
    private DataSet _dataSet;
    private BindingSource _bsrc;
    private OleDbDataAdapter _dAdapter;
    private OleDbCommandBuilder _cBuilder;
    private DataTable _dTable;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //create the connection string
        string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data      
        Source='C:\\Documents and Settings\\dorota\\Moje dokumenty\\Visual Studio  
        2010\\Projects\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\artb.mdb'";

        //create the database query
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Samochody";
        System.Data.DataSet DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
        _dataSet = DtSet;
        //create an OleDbDataAdapter to execute the query
        OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connString);
        dAdapter.FillSchema(_dataSet, SchemaType.Source);

        _dAdapter = dAdapter;
        //create a command builder
        OleDbCommandBuilder cBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(_dAdapter);
        _cBuilder = cBuilder;
        //create a DataTable to hold the query results
        DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
        _dTable = dTable;
        //fill the DataTable
        _dAdapter.Fill(_dTable);
        //_dAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Samochody", "Table");

        _dAdapter.Fill(_dataSet);

        // --------------------- to datagridview !

        //BindingSource to sync DataTable and DataGridView
        BindingSource _bsrc = new BindingSource();

        //set the BindingSource DataSource
        //bSource.DataSource = _dTable;
        _bsrc.DataSource = _dTable;
        //_bsrc = bSource;
        //set the DataGridView DataSource
        dataGridView1.DataSource = _bsrc;
    }
    }
```

and here...  :

```
    private void sqlsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //int i=_dAdapter.Update(_dTable);
        _dAdapter.Update(_dataSet.Tables["Samochody"]);
        //_dAdapter.Update(_dataSet,"Samochody");
    }
```

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ok. I have changed sqlsave method for this

```
    private void sqlsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    try
    {
        //_dAdapter.Update(_dataSet.Tables["Samochody"]);
         OleDbCommand oldb= _cBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
         int i=oldb.ExecuteNonQuery();
         System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(i+" rows affected.");
        //_dAdapter.Update(_dataSet,"Samochody");
    }catch(OleDbException oldbex){
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(oldbex.ToString());
    }
```

and now I get finally sth more informative than "Error in"

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: ExecuteNonQuery
>   requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current
>   state is closed.

so let me changed sth and I will let you know if this is it!

//--------------------------------

no. no. too fast, can't last. now while trying to save I've got exception again,
connectin is opened, but (I can't post the image) when I debug this I see that my object of OleDbCommand type as _commandText has

> "UPDATE Samochody SET Item=?, Data dyspozycji autem od=?, ..."

and so on.
I think this is the reason. Am I right? What to do?

Comment: You're mixing and matching different methods.  The `ExecuteNonQuery` requires an open connection — the CommandBuilder won't provide that for you.  You need to put your Update command into your DataAdapter and run your Update.  You may have to provide your own Update method.  Make sure your table has a PrimaryKey index.

Comment: @LarsTech you said "to put your Update command into your DataAdapter". isn't it ok if I do update on my _cBuilder which is private field in this class and is initialized by _dAdapter in button1_Click command? Connection is opened. And in sqlsave_Click() I have:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer:

> But a better approach would be to use drag-and-drop and learn form the code.

```
Select Data|View Datasources. Your dataset should be visible in the DataSources Window.
Drag a table to a (new) form. VS2005 will add a load of components and a few lines of code.
```

The form will now have a instance of the dataset and that is your reference point for Adapter.Fill and .Update methods.

Easy and works great! : D
I've found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/548124/1141471

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a connection for your `OleDbDataAdapter`. Try it something like this:

**The example is different from your code but it shows the declaration of New Connection and passing it to the OleDbDataAdapter**

```
        string connetionString = null;
        OleDbConnection connection ;
        OleDbDataAdapter oledbAdapter ;
        OleDbCommandBuilder oledbCmdBuilder ;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        int i = 0;
        string sql = null;
        connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Your mdb filename;";
        connection = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
        sql = "select * from tblUsers";
        try
        {
            connection.Open();  // your code must have like this
            oledbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
            oledbCmdBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(oledbAdapter);
            oledbAdapter.Fill(ds);
            for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[2] = "neweamil@email.com";
            }
            oledbAdapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
            connection.Close();
            MessageBox.Show ("Email address updates !");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: I have a connection `
                 OleDbCommand oldb= _cBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
                 oldb.Connection.Open();
                 
                 int i=oldb.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(i+" rows affected.");
                //_dAdapter.Update(_dataSet,"Samochody");
                 oldb.Connection.Close();
            }catch(OleDbException oldbex){
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(oldbex.ToString());
            }`

Comment: _cBuilder is stored in private field of this class as the rest of Ole Objects, take a look at the top of main code. I hope it is ok if I store this object which is initialized in other click method (?) I don't have to create everytime new aDapter,BindingSource etc if I want to affect this same data from different functions of the same Windows Form - do I?